# How to split csv data by value

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

im in a situation where i have to plot this csv data like below.

```
"x1","x2","y"
-0.626453810742332,0.409401839650934,-1
0.183643324222082,1.68887328620405,1
-0.835628612410047,1.58658843344197,-1
```

And the information of the label y should be expressed in the form of color.

I tried coding like this.

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

df['x'] = df['x1'] + df['x2']

for value in df['y']:
    if value == 1:
        df['y1'] = df['y']
    else:
        df['y-1'] = df['y']
print(df['y1'])

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y1'], c='red')
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y-1'], c='blue')
plt.show()
```

but this didn't give me what i wanted. 
and i ran `print(df['y1'])` to see what went wrong and the result is

```
0     -1
1      1
2     -1
3      1
4     -1
.
.
.
```

i splitted by value 1 or -1 but still mixed. how can i split this by value 1 or -1?

Comment: `df['y1'] = df['y]` just copies the entire series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='x1', y='x2', hue='y')
```

Or you can use `groupby`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for k,d in df.groupby('y'):

    d.plot.scatter(x='x1',y='x2', label=k)
```

Answer (score 0):

By equalling `df['y1']` to  `df['y']`, the entire column is copied. Instead, you can do like this:

`for value in df['y']:
    if value == 1:
        df['y1'] = value
    else:
        df['y-1'] = value
print(df['y1'])`